# TPCH Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, performance

The following query is taking 5 hours so far to run:

```
INSERT $LINEITEM_PUBLIC     SELECT  *
    FROM  LINEITEM
    WHERE  L_PARTKEY  IN ( SELECT P_PARTKEY FROM  $PART_PUBLIC )
      AND  L_SUPPKEY  IN ( SELECT S_SUPPKEY FROM  $SUPPLIER_PUBLIC )
      AND  L_ORDERKEY IN ( SELECT O_ORDERKEY FROM  $ORDERS_PUBLIC );
```

I added all required indexes but nothing seems to be helping. The Query Explain Plan prints the following:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type   | possible_keys                  | key         | key_len | ref                            | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | INSERT      | $LINEITEM_PUBLIC | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                           |     NULL |     NULL | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | $ORDERS_PUBLIC   | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY                        | O_ORDERDATE | 3       | NULL                           | 12826617 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | LINEITEM         | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,LINEITEM_FK2,L_SUPPKEY | PRIMARY     | 4       | TPCH.$ORDERS_PUBLIC.O_ORDERKEY |        3 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | $SUPPLIER_PUBLIC | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY     | 4       | TPCH.LINEITEM.L_SUPPKEY        |        1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | $PART_PUBLIC     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY     | 4       | TPCH.LINEITEM.L_PARTKEY        |        1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Any recommendations on how this query can be optimized?

**Update:**
The size of the tables in the previous query is as follows:

- LINEITEM: 60M records
- $ORDERS_PUBLIC: 13M records
- $SUPPLIER_PUBLIC: 92K records
- $PART_PUBLIC: 2M records

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is an index starting with `O_ORDERKEY`.

`IN (SELECT ...)` may be optimized poorly (depending on version); try this:

```
INSERT $LINEITEM_PUBLIC
    SELECT  l.*
        FROM LINEITEM AS l
        WHERE  EXISTS( SELECT * FROM  $PART_PUBLIC     WHERE P_PARTKEY  = L_PARTKEY )
          AND  EXISTS( SELECT * FROM  $SUPPLIER_PUBLIC WHERE S_SUPPKEY  = L_SUPPKEY )
          AND  EXISTS( SELECT * FROM  $ORDERS_PUBLIC   WHERE O_ORDERKEY = L_ORDERKEY );
```